# What's the purpose of "true" in bash "if sudo true; then"

Tags: bash, sudo

I've hacked together this bash script which tests if the user has superuser privileges and if they don't it asks for them.  Ultimately I'm trying to invert the second 'if' statement so that I can remove the following two lines (the echo "password ok" and the else on the following line)

```
# Root user only
if [[ "$EUID" != 0 ]]; then
    sudo -k # make sure to ask for password on next sudo
    if sudo true; then
        echo "Password ok"
    else
        echo "Aborting script"
        exit 1
    fi
fi

echo "do my ops"
```

Is the purpose of "true" on the fourth line just a null-statement?

I need to invert the test on the fourth line, how do I do so?  Here is what I've tried:

```
if sudo false; then  
if sudo true == false; then
if [!(sudo true)]; then
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/10552711/537980

Comment: you can just remove the `echo "Password ok"`, if you wish.

Comment: @JeffSchaller  I'm trying to shorten the snippet, I've tried simply removing the "echo Password ok" line but bash complains "syntax error near unexpected token 'else'.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor following that link it seems all I need do is put an exclamation mark in front of the sudo and then I can remove both the echo and the else, and now i've tested it, that works, thanks.

Comment: In passing, you probably ought to redirect the error message to the error stream: `echo "Aborting script" >&2`

Comment: I'm a little triggered by your "sudo -k" line. If I set my sudo to cache the credentials that's what I want. I don't want random utilities to wipe that out.

Comment: @pipe If the script is a random utility then perhaps you might be right, but in my use case it's a script in a private project.

Comment: This check is for convenience (fail early if the invoking user won't be able to use sudo), not security (prevent users from running the script), right?

Comment: @Dennis yes, that's my use case.

Comment: It would have probably saved you a lot of time to just swap which code is executed instead.  Not that it's not a valid question in itself--I'm just sayin'...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`true` in bash isn't a keyword, it's a program that instantly exits with a successful exit code.
Likewise, `false` is a program that exits with an unsuccessful exit code.

You can try this out by running both programs from your terminal, and then reading the `$?` variable, which contains the exit code of the last program;

```
true
echo $? # 0
false
echo $? #1
```

`if sudo true` isn't equivalent to `if sudo == true`. `if sudo true` is running the `true` program using `sudo`, and checking the exit code.

Therefore:

`if sudo false; then` is running the program `false` as sudo. The return will always be false.

`if sudo true == false` will run the program `true` with the arguments `==` and `false` using `sudo`. This obviously isn't want you intended.

`if [!(sudo true)]` is invalid syntax.

What you are probably looking for is

```
if ! sudo true;
```

Comment: As a slightly pedantic correction to the first sentence: *in bash*, `true` and `false` are "builtins", commands interpreted directly by the shell; *in Unix-like systems in general*, they also exist as standalone programs on the file system. The difference doesn't matter that much here, but as far as I know, `sudo true` will be running the standalone program, not the bash builtin.

Comment: PS: my favourite summaries of `true` and `false` are the titles on their man pages: `true - do nothing, successfully` and `false - do nothing, unsuccessfully`

Comment: @IMSoP That's deep.

Comment: @IMSoP I'm curious, what's the point of having shell builtins that exactly duplicate the behavior of some programs? I'm tempted to guess performance, but I'd not expect `true` to ever be called nearly often enough to matter.

Comment: @JohnDvorak Yes, probably performance, plus they're really easy to implement, so "why not". `true` and `false` might not be the most used builtins, but if you write `while true; do echo infinite loop; done` skipping the overhead of calling an external executable every time around the loop might be significant.

Comment: If `true` didn't exist, the code in the question shows why one might need to invent it! It's a minimal program that can only fail if the system it's on is truly borked. So one can use it to establish if one's access credentials  are OK.

Comment: Historical note: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEFBR14 (the same idea on an ancient IBM mainframe, and probably the  shortest ever program to have a bug in it).

Comment: In AT&T SYSV Unix, "true" was a shell script /bin/true, which consisted of a large copyright notice in comments...and nothing else.

Comment: @IMSoP: But `true` and `false` don't quite “do nothing”; they support `--help` and `--version` options.

Answer (score 23):

I feel like the accepted answer didn't actually answer your question?

The **purpose** of doing this is to check that you can actually `sudo`.

**How** this check is performed is via the `true` program as explained in the accepted answer.

Comment: Essentially, this.  Alternative could be to check if the user is in sudoers group, but just running `sudo true` is also easy enough of a way, although a bit hacky.

Comment: Note that this also requires `sudo` to be installed, so the checks wouldn't be entirely equivalent... you could be in the sudoers group and still not be able to sudo. (This can especially come up if you're e.g. writing a script to setup a new image from a minimal rootfs tarball, which might not have sudo.)

Comment: The OP wants to drop out if you cannot sudo, and get rid of two lines rather than have an else following a noop.

Comment: You're right that I'm essentially asking two questions and the accepted answer answered the other one about inverting the test line - I probably should have kept it to one question!

Comment: And, conversely, you can also be able to `sudo` without being in the sudoers group if you (either personally or as a member of some _other_ group) are listed in `/etc/sudoers`. But even `sudo true` is not infallible, as `sudo` access can be granted for only specific commands, so you may be able to `sudo true`, but not to `sudo something_else`, or vice-versa. There's no iron-clad way to test other than by trying to run the command you actually want to run with `sudo`.

Comment: Also, you can be in the `sudoers` group and not be able to `sudo` because the `sudoers` group is not listed in the `sudoers` file.  A group with the four letters `sudo` in its name is not a valid indication of whether or not a user in that group can do any particular thing or anything at all using `sudo`.

Answer (score 5):

As I see in this script. It is just checking if sudo is enabled, that is it..

true just returns true.

So in this case if they need to run any command with sudo it checks at start first, asking the password only one time.

The condition works like this: if sudo are executing the true command correctly, it will return true for the if condition, then sudo is enabled and the user typed the password correctly, else you typed the password wrong or sudo is not enabled, the  script must not continue.

The other commands do not need to ask sudo password, because your authentication are sucessfully in first time (but this depends on the sudo configuration, so this scripts depends much in the environment configuration)

The 'echo password ok' demonstrate that too. the shell script will not ask the password anymore.

Comment: The only commands that run through sudo there are `sudo true` and `sudo -k`. The latter explicitly doesn't require a password. None of the other commands in the script run via sudo, so of course they will not require passwords, regardless of if the authentication was successful the first time.

Comment: I wrote: "So in this case if they need to run any command with sudo it checks at start first, asking the password only one time. "